# How to make a sound play onClick complying with HTML4?

Tags: javascript, audio, onclick, html4

I've got the page working magnificently in Chrome, but older versions of IE are giving it trouble. The audio tag isn't recognized, so I'm wondering: How can I make a sound play after the image is clicked? I have attached the relevant code below. 
Again, it works in Chrome. I just don't know how to approach this for IE versions 7 and 8, because it doesn't accept the audio tag OR me creating a new Audio object in my javascript. I'll take any help I can get, but I am very inexperienced with JQuery.

```
<img id="Unique" src="bellTop.jpg" width="17%" height="20%" title="A Major"
onclick="funct1()" />
<script>
function funct1() {
var willPlay= new Audio();
willPlay.src="pathToAudio/Song.mp3";
willPlay.play(); }
</script>
```

EDIT: I understand the object and embed tags. I don't want a player to appear; I want the sound file to be hidden on the page, but when an image is clicked, it plays.

EDIT 2: Problem solved (mainly)!Here's the code that works to get around the problem!

```
<span id="dummyspan"></span>

<img src="imageName.jpg" width="17%" height="20%" onClick="playSound('SongName.mp3')"> 

<script>
function playSound(surl) {
document.getElementById("dummyspan").innerHTML=
"<embed src='"+surl+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>"; }
</script>
```

It seems that you can create an empty span, embed an audio file in it, and then call it up with the javascript function! It does take a few seconds to load, but I'm willing to bet that anyone still using IE8 and below is used to that by now.

Comment: It's not the tag that's the problem, it's simply that IE 8- don't support the ECMA specification for `Audio`. Take a look at shims for IE: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: @KodleeYin, you beat me to it!

Comment: I can suggest this Plugin for cross-browser audio: http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS

Comment: Thanks guys! I seemed to have found some half-way cheat around this problem. I've posted the code in the question; thanks again!